# google pagerank curl call using php

Tags: lamp, google-ranking

i read an article regarding google rank and i wanted to create a php script that get the page rank using curl in php - i endded up using this script:

http://www.brightyoursite.com/blog/2010/06/01/use-php-to-get-google-page-rank/

now when i run it i get on my ubuntu:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in
>   /var/www/googlerank.php ....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to install `php5-curl`.

On Ubuntu or Debian, you can do this by running either `apt-get install php5-curl` or `aptitude install php5-curl` depending on which command you use to manage your packages.

You can see whether it is currently installed or not using the command `aptitude show php5-curl`.

It is always good to keep a PHP script with only this code:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

The above code will print a lot of information about server, the request, installed packages, etc. that are useful for diagnosing issues. If `php5-curl` is installed, you should find a section for 'curl' in the output here.